# Stateful Widget inside of Stateful Widget: Updating UI

Tags: flutter, dart

Good evening!

I'm hung up on this one. I have a widget called RevenueBarChart()--stateful. This widget uses a Future Builder to get data from an API and display the data in a bar chart. I'm trying to place this bar chart within another widget which is also stateful. The problem is that the chart stays stuck on the loading spinner and doesn't actually update and show in the UI. The data comes back from my API just fine, I just don't know how to implement code to display my new chart. Whether in didChangeDepencies, didUpdateWidget or something else. My code is below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import '../providers/companies_provider.dart';
import '../charts/revenue_bar_chart.dart';

class RevenueScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/revenue-screen';

  @override
  _RevenueScreenState createState() => _RevenueScreenState();
}

class _RevenueScreenState extends State<RevenueScreen>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<RevenueScreen> {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  Future _historicalData;
  Future _historicalQuarterlyData;

  var _isInit = true;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      final companyTicker = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as String;
      final loadedCompany = Provider.of<Companies>(context, listen: false)
          .findByTicker(companyTicker);

      _historicalData =
          Companies().getHistoricalData(loadedCompany.tickerSymbol);
      _historicalQuarterlyData =
          Companies().getQuarterlyHistoricalData(loadedCompany.tickerSymbol);
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    final companyTicker = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as String;
    final loadedCompany = Provider.of<Companies>(context, listen: false)
        .findByTicker(companyTicker);
    var truncNumber = NumberFormat.compact();

    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 250,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: RevenueBarChart(),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              height: 50,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Yearly Revenue',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            FutureBuilder(
              future: _historicalData,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.data == null) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 50,
                    child: Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        width: 0.5,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    height: 225,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 60, right: 60),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          dense: true,
                          leading: Text(
                            snapshot.data[index]['date'].toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          trailing: Text(
                            truncNumber
                                .format(snapshot.data[index]['revenue'])
                                .toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
              width: 1,
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              height: 50,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Quarterly Revenue',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            FutureBuilder(
              future: _historicalQuarterlyData,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.data == null) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 50,
                    child: Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        width: 0.5,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    height: 225,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 60, right: 60),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          dense: true,
                          leading: Text(
                            snapshot.data[index]['date'].toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          trailing: Text(
                            truncNumber
                                .format(snapshot.data[index]['revenue'])
                                .toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
              width: 5,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:stockmarketapp/models/financial_modeling_prep_HD.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';

import '../providers/companies_provider.dart';

class RevenueBarChart extends StatefulWidget with ChangeNotifier {
  @override
  _RevenueBarChartState createState() => _RevenueBarChartState();
}

class _RevenueBarChartState extends State<RevenueBarChart> with ChangeNotifier {
  Future<List<IncomeStatementBC>> _revenueDataForChart;
  var _isInit = true;
  bool isFirstLabel;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      final companyTicker = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as String;
      final loadedCompany = Provider.of<Companies>(context, listen: false)
          .findByTicker(companyTicker);

      _revenueDataForChart =
          Companies().getIncomeStatement(loadedCompany.tickerSymbol);
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final companyTicker = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as String;
    final loadedCompany = Provider.of<Companies>(context, listen: false)
        .findByTicker(companyTicker);
    var truncNumber = NumberFormat.compact();
    isFirstLabel = true;

    final List<Color> color = <Color>[];
    color.add(Colors.black12.withOpacity(1));
    color.add(Color.fromRGBO(0, 128, 255, .5));
    color.add(Color.fromRGBO(0, 128, 255, .7));
    color.add(Color.fromRGBO(0, 128, 255, .9));

    final List<double> stops = <double>[];
    stops.add(0);
    stops.add(0.3);
    stops.add(.4);
    stops.add(.6);

    final LinearGradient gradients =
    LinearGradient(
      colors: color,
      stops: stops,
      transform: GradientRotation(
          540.toDouble() * 3.14 / 270
      ),
      begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      end: Alignment.topCenter,
    );

    return Container(
      height: 250,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: FutureBuilder<List<IncomeStatementBC>>(
        future: _revenueDataForChart,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<IncomeStatementBC>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data != null) {
            return SfCartesianChart(
              onAxisLabelRender: (AxisLabelRenderArgs args) {
                if (args.axisName == 'primaryYAxis' && isFirstLabel) {
                  args.text = ' ';
                  isFirstLabel = false;
                }
              },
              plotAreaBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
              zoomPanBehavior: ZoomPanBehavior(enablePanning: true),
              trackballBehavior: TrackballBehavior(
                  enable: true,
                  activationMode: ActivationMode.singleTap,
                  tooltipSettings: InteractiveTooltip(
                    enable: true,
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    format: 'point.y',
                  )
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 20,
                  right: 20,
                  top: 10,
                  bottom: 10
              ),
              primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
                labelAlignment: LabelAlignment.start,
                maximumLabels: 5,
                labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                majorGridLines: MajorGridLines(color: Colors.grey, width: 0),
                majorTickLines: MajorTickLines(size: 0),
              ),
              primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
                  numberFormat: NumberFormat.compact(),
                  opposedPosition: true,
                  tickPosition: TickPosition.inside,
                  maximumLabels: 2,
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  labelAlignment: LabelAlignment.start,
                  majorGridLines: MajorGridLines(color: Colors.grey, width: 0),
                  majorTickLines: MajorTickLines(size: 0),
                  minorGridLines: MinorGridLines(color: Colors.grey, width: 0),
                  minorTickLines: MinorTickLines(size: 0)
              ),
              series: <ChartSeries<IncomeStatementBC, String>>[
                ColumnSeries<IncomeStatementBC, String>(
                  gradient: gradients,
                  dataSource: snapshot.data,
                  xValueMapper: (IncomeStatementBC data, _) => data.date,
                  yValueMapper: (IncomeStatementBC data, _) => data.revenue,
                )
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your RevenueBarChart widget? It seems as if the problem is in it

Comment: @David gotcha! Just added it

Comment: I don't think the problem is having two stateful widgets. You'd need to explicitly save some variable and access it below to cause a problem. Try adding a `print` statement to the end of your `getIncomeStatement` method, either by modifying it or using `_revenueDataForChart.then(...)` and see if it actually returns, or use a debugger.

Comment: @David everything you just said went completely over my head lol but you're right I made a silly mistake somewhere. It works now, thanks!

Comment: Ok, sorry for being unclear, but that's great it works now!

Comment: @user13821109 It would be great if you could share why it works now, I seem to be in exactly the same position :)

Comment: @theLastNightTrain I wish I could but sadly it stopped working again. If I figure out a new solution I’ll post it here to let you know!

Comment: @theLastNightTrain I said I'd let you know when I've figured the problem out and alas for my situation I have. I'm not sure if this will apply to you or if you still need assistance but the issue wasn't a stateful widget inside of a stateful widget. The UI should update just fine in this scenario, so don't worry about that. In my situation I was getting null values for my class, that I hadn't checked for when getting data from API. I hope either this piece of information helps or you fix your issue soon!

Comment: Thanks for the update @user13821109, I don't recall how I resolved it but I suspect it was a similar null somewhere! :)